# Mealplan: Allow ordering until 9am

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Imagine you have a meal service and everyday there is a different meal which customers can order.

```
Mon, Dec 12: Pasta
Tue, Dec 13: Pizza
Wed, Dec 14: Gnocci
```

Orders are possible until 9am.

This mean Monday on 8am customers may order Pasta for today, at 9:15am they are no longer allowed to order for today.

How to handle this is with PostgreSQL.

I see two ways:

1. Create a cron job which switches the column "orderable" to False.
2. Create a view which calculates the field "orderable" on the fly.

Is there a feasible third or forth way?

Which way is simple and robust?

Comment: Do they get the next day's item to choose or do they get nothing?

Comment: @Vérace on monday 10am should be allowed to order for Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, ... (does this answer you question?)

Comment: That's grand - but what happens to somebody who wishes to eat lunch (I presume it's lunch?) and who wants to order at 09:30?

Comment: @Vérace Those who don't order on time are out of luck. That's not like a pizza service which you can call any time. Every day there are three meals. You can choose one, but you need to do this on time. Quality vs Quantity. Or in this case "Quality vs Flexibility". There are very flexible food services which deliver with big meals with a low price. But that's not the business of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the dates in a date column, you can use a simple `CASE` to choose, which meal is selected.

The result if the query, depends when you look for the example, it will choose pasta before 9 in the morning a Minute later and you would get  gnocchi, you only have to enter the menus ahead of time

In an event you could delete the old menus, but that is not necessary, as you will not have millions of rows.

> ```
> CREATe TABLe "OrDERS" ("orderdate" date, "food" varchar(40))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO "OrDERS" VALUES (CURRENT_DATE  ,'Pasta'), (CURRENT_DATE  + INTERVAL '1 day','Gnocchi')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT to_char("orderdate",'Dy, Mon DD'), "food" FROM "OrDERS" 
> WHERE "orderdate" = 
>        CASE WHEN NOW() < now()::date + interval '9h' THEN now()::date
>             ELSE now()::date + INTERVAL '1 day'
>        END
> ```
>
> ```
> to_char     | food  
> :---------- | :-----
> Tue, Dec 22 | Gnocci
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ac4d32c6afe16302952321f35cc99cc6)*